# Salesforce mobile SDK in China

Tags: mobilesdk

I have a small question for the community regarding Mobile SDK and China.

We are currently setting a mobile app that use Mobile SDK that is calling/pushing information from/to Salesforce.

The salesforce organization is hosted in Europe that contains all the data.

Salesforce support told us that there are no issue to access Salesforce from a browser in China in this configuration but we would like to confirm that our app will also work perfectly in China.

Does anyone knows if the SDK mobile app will be able to connect to the Salesforce organization hosted in Europe and call the data from China ?

We would like to know if there could be any issues concerning, access, security, performance or restriction with using our mobile app in China with a Salesforce organization based in Europe.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Best regards,

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce1 app is certainly available and IOS, apple store are fully supported in China.  However, the Google play store is not accessible from China if you are using the Android system.  As a workaround, you can download SF1 APK manually [here](https://salesforce1android.herokuapp.com).

Thanks

Comment: Hello Vinay, Thank you for your answer. My question was also about accessing Salesforce using a custom mobile app using Salesforce SDK. Do you know if there could be any issue with this ? I guess it is just a login to Salesforce so it should work.

Comment: Yes,  It will work as expected.

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot for your answer Vinay !